# How to convert geographic coordinates inside a list of lists inside a dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, coordinates, wkt

I have a dataframe that consists of coordinates, and they are grouped inside a list of lists. The end goal here is I want to convert them into a Polygon Well-Known-Text (WKT). How can I do it?
[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZPDo.png)
Thanks!

Comment: this library could be helpful : https://pypi.org/project/geodaisy/ look for the chapter **convert GeoJson to WKT**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ranifisch Hi! Tried this code so far but no luck yet:


`import geodaisy.converters as convert
for index,row in df_isochrone.iterrows():
  row['wkt'] = []
  geojson = {"type": row['geometry.type'], "coordinates": [row['geometry.coordinates']]}
  geojson = convert.geojson_to_wkt(geojson)
  row['wkt'].append(geojson)
`

Comment: It's not returning anything :( Or probably my syntax is just wrong

Comment: Oh nevermind. I was able to solve it already. Thanks!